# can you append an object to an already instantiated object in python?

Tags: python, object, append

is there a way to add in an appending method into a class that inherits from the object class in python.

here's my problem... I have a Sentence, Word, and Character class... and I would like to be able to append a character to a sentience... but when I do

```
    string_a = Character('a')
    string_b = Character('b')
    string_c = Character('c')
    str_list = [string_a, string_b, string_c]
    # this part works fine
    sentience = Sentence(str_list)
    # this part does not work... but it makes sense why not, because I'm adding two  data types to one object. 
    # but sense sentience inherits from character, and it's really just a list of characters... I was thinking there must be some way to append another character to it. 
    new_str_list = [sentience + string_a]          

    new_sentience = Sentence(new_str_list)
```

python throws an error, which makes sense... but all this to say is there a way to append to a specific instantiated Sentience class (which as I mentioned before is just a subclass of the object class) or add a character instantiation to a pre-existing sentience object? the problem is that I'm making a Character/word/sentience/paragraph lexical tokenizer... that goes through HTML, and I wan't to keep the html intact, so I'm building a class structure like this, because things like HTML tags have there own data type, so I can add them back in later.

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your Character and Sentence classes?

Comment: and the actual error you get back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is override the addition operator for Sentence.

If you add something like the following to Sentence you can define what happens when you add a Sentence to an object.

```
  def __add__(self, object):
    #Now you have access to self (the first operand of the addition) and the second operand of the addition, you'd probably want to do something like the following:
    if type(object) == Sentence:
      return self.words + object.words
    if type(object) == list:
      return self.words + list
    if type(object) == Character:
      return self.words + str(Character)
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably can't work if `Sentence` is a container like a `list`

```
sentience + string_a
```

I'd guess that you need something like

```
new_str_list = sentience + [string_a]
```

but it's impossible to know without seeing the class